# Why $\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i\omega t}) = \frac{i}{2} (e^{-i \omega t} - e^{i\omega t})$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Let $i := \sqrt{-1}$, $f$ be the frequency ($\frac1p$), and  $\omega := 2 \pi f$.

From page 3 [here](http://www.enm.bris.ac.uk/admin/courses/EMa2/Lecture%20Notes%2009-10/LSPDE2.pdf), why does $\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i\omega t}) = \frac{i}{2} (e^{-i \omega t} - e^{i\omega t})$?

I understand that the LHS's $\frac{1}{2i}$ is multiplied by $\frac ii$ to get the RHS's $\frac i2$, but I don't understand how the contents of the parentheses changes?

Comment: Because $$\frac1i=-i$$

Comment: I get it now thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Just that $\frac{1}{i} = - i$, so by distributing the minus sign,
$$\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i\omega t}) = -\frac{i}{2}(e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i\omega t}) = \frac{i}{2}(e^{-i\omega t} - e^{i\omega t}). $$

Comment: Dear downvoter: Thank you; my rep is now a multiple of ten. That's been bugging me for a while. :D